# How do i put content of element into array? (for Polymer dom-repeat)

Tags: arrays, polymer, polymer-1.0

let me describe my situation and what i want to do. 
Let's say i have 2 custom elements

x-register.html and x-register-card.html

In x-register.html is one static x-register-card but there is also button to add more cards (up to 5).

How exactly do i put content of my x-register-card.html to array and then use it in my main element (x-register.html) as

```
<templare is="dom-repeat" item="cardArray" as="card">
  <section> <!-- wrapper for each card -->
    <x-register-card></x-register-card> <!-- dynamic element -->
  </section> 
</template>
```

Here is code of  my x-register-card.html

```
<template>
  <style include="shared-styles">
  /* Element */
  :host {
    display: block;
  }

</style>

  <h4>Register</h4>
  <paper-input label="Username"></paper-input>
  <paper-input label="First Name></paper-input>
  <paper-input label="Surname"></paper-input>
  <paper-input label="Password" type="password"></paper-input>

<template>
<script>
(function() {
  'use strict';
  Polymer({

    /**
     * Element configuration.
     */
    is: 'x-register-card',
    property: {
      role: {
        type: String,
        value: ""
      }
    }


  });
})();
```

Property role in x-register-card is just String used as `<x-register-card role="My friend"><x-register-card>`

I am trying to grab content (maybe it's ID and push it to array) - let's say i have already 3 items in array so im my x-register.html are shown 3 register-cards. How do i do that?

//Question edited

Comment: What is inside your **<x-register-card>**? What are properties inside there?

Comment: This question doesn't provide enough information, please improve the question and add more code.

Comment: Question edited, I added more of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<template is="dom-repeat" items="[[cards]]" as="card">
  <section>
    <x-register-card header="[[card.header]]" text="[[card.text]]"></x-register-card>
  </section> 
</template>

<script>
  ...
  function add() {
    this.push('cards', {header: 'card', text: 'some text'});
  }
  ...
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, according to your answer i was able to figure out how can i make my code working as expected!